# How can I delete a group in Viber?

Tags: viber-messenger

I made a group in Viber. I wanna get out all of members from this group. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Viber.
2. Go to the group conversation screen.
3. Swipe the group you want to leave.
4. Select 'delete' then select 'delete and Leave group'.

Comment: there isn't "leave/ delete group" what can I do?

Comment: With the new version as of March 2017, Swipe the screen to the left OR Tap on the 3 dots in the chat header & select **Chat Info** . Then you will find the **Leave and Delete** command  (go to the bottom of the page if you have many users). You will delete the group conversation from your chats list only, you won't delete the group. If you are the admin of the group you will be able to delete the group.

Comment: @Dush it's been a while, consider posting your comment as an answer because comments are not really for answering the question. (The question has been unprotected)

Answer (score 1):

Directly from **Viber** :

> ***Groups cannot be deleted by any one user***. When a user leaves a group,
>
> the group continues to exist with all remaining participants. When all
> participants leave a group, it will automatically be deleted.

[How do I use group conversations on my Android device?](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1476543-temp-4-3---how-do-i-use-group-conversations-on-my-android-device-#Deleting%20a%20group)

Comment: Does this mean that if one user (the group admin in this case) has changed his phone number we will never be able to edit/delete the group anymore?